# Camera Rotation Animation

Tags: paraview

I have simulated a rotating cube filled with particles by moving the gravity vector rather than changing all of the geometry. I want to use the ParaView animation tools to rotate the camera to keep the gravity vector pointing down so it all looks right. When moving the camera (not animations) I would use the rotate 90 degrees tools.
[image]

How would I achieve this effect for an animation?

**EDIT:**
I have done it using a video editor as an extra step after ParaView, this is the effect I am going for: https://youtu.be/rym2fdKkPps

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You cannot animate GUI button usage with animation. However you can animate camera position and orientation as finely as you want. 
Try adding a camera track to the animation track of type "Interpolate Camera Location".

Add the two positions you want and set the time to be very close.

Comment: I tried that but couldn't get the camera to rotate in the way I am trying to make it. I know I can't just make it press buttons for me, but I'm looking for an animation function similar to the function provided by the rotate buttons.

Comment: Apologies for the delay, I ended up rotating it in my video editing software. However, having now experimented with your suggestion I have found that it does mostly work. I may need to do some scripting to get a smooth rotation but it's a step forward. Thanks!

(P.S. the state file is no longer downloadable at that URL).